# How to properly position an HTML elelment (a divider line) in between elements of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to put an HTML element in between a table header and table rows?

Something like the code I have in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oawUUlP6vnkXSIrWwVXO?p=preview):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>       
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
<div style="background-color: #848484; width: 100%; height:1px; margin:0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>        
    <td>Value 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My current way of achieving this is putting the divider line div after the table and using position relative to place it in between the table elements. But if the height of the table header or body changes, my position relative line may not appear in between the header and body anymore.

What is the best way to insert this divider line so that it is always between the table header and body?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need more information or I am being unclear.

Comment: You can't put divs between table rows,it's invalid HTML. What effect are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `tr + tr {border-bottom: 1px solid grey}`

Comment: Why not just apply borders to the table cells or rows or whatever? Like you would do in Excel or so if you wanted a line between anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need additional markup to put a line in your table. Just use CSS:

```css
th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #848484;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* remove space between cells */
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to do it is by using THEAD and TBODY and then write some css that does the same as your DIV

HTML

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

CSS

```
thead {border-bottom:1px solid #848484;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-bottom` to add the separator, and use the `:last-child` selector to remove the separator for the last row.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/htkjwdko/)

#### HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>       
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>        
    <td>Value 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>        
    <td>Value 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
tr {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 11px solid grey;
}

tr:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```